# Create new git repository out of two existing ones

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two repositories, A and B, and now I want to make a third one (C) that has two submodules, subA and subB. But I want to replay the whole history of those two repositories, as if they were commited alongside each other.

So I want to go to repository C and create submodules subA and subB with their first commits. Then search by date which had the next commit, and then commit that one. And so on until today. Of course, only the main branch.

I need this because i want to have the whole history of those two repositories together.

Is there a script that would do this?

Comment: Do the repositories need to stay as submodules? If not it might be easier to add both as remotes and merge those in a combined **master** branch.
I could explain this further (if the submodules are not needed)

Comment: try this link https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/16/merge-git-repositories/ I can write the answer in few hours